# How to put getAlbumTable() into a service?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

What I really dislike in ZF2 is that `Controller` is aware of storage engine (*This is a clear violation of SRP*) and that a storage engine has a concept of `Tables`. I believe that this is not correct way, and Controller should only be aware of services (while only services should be aware of Storage engine)

```
class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $albumTable;

    public function getAlbumTable()
    {
        if (!$this->albumTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
        }
        return $this->albumTable;
    }
```

Nowhere in manual I could find on how to put that into a Service and make controller only aware of actions. **How would you put that into a service?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that's how it's done in the official tutorial, but in my opinion it's not the best approach. Instead you want to inject your dependencies into your controller class via. its constructor. This makes it easier to see what's going on, and easier to test.

To do this, modify your controller class to add an appropriate constructor:

```
class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $albumTable;

    public function __construct(AlbumTable $albumTable)
    {
        $this->albumTable = $albumTable;
    }
}
```

Then, remove the *invokable* line in your `module.config.php` for this controller, since it can no longer just be instantiated without any arguments. Instead, you define a *factory* to tell ZF how to instantiate the class. In your `Module.php`:

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager;
use Album\Controller\AlbumController;

class Module
{
    public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Album\Controller\Album' => function(ControllerManager $cm) {
                    $sm = $cm->getServiceLocator();
                    $albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');

                    $controller = new AlbumController($albumTable);

                    return $controller;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

(Alternatively you could create a separate factory class to do this.)

In your controller actions you can then access the album table via. `$this->albumTable` instead of `$this->getAlbumTable()`.

Hopefully you can see that this approach can easily be modified to inject a service class instead. If you want your album table injected into the service, and the service injected into the controller; you might end up with something like this:

```
class Module
{
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                    $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'AlbumTableGateway' => function($sm) {
                    [etc...]
                },
                'Album\Service\AlbumService' => function($sm) {
                    $albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');

                    return new AlbumService($albumTable);
                 }
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Album\Controller\Album' => function(ControllerManager $cm) {
                    $sm = $cm->getServiceLocator();
                    $albumService = $sm->get('Album\Service\AlbumService');

                    $controller = new AlbumController($albumService);

                    return $controller;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $albumService;

    public function __construct(AlbumService $albumService)
    {
        $this->albumService = $albumService;
    }

    public function someAction()
    {
        // do stuff with $this->albumService
    }
}
```